# Vlookup formula in excel

Tags: excel

I was hoping someone could offer me a little help please on a formula.  In one of my cells I use a vlookup to search for the colour in B12 and match it to the colour on another worksheet called cars.

Now this works perfectly fine, but after running the formula I have to select the last row of data and press control & d, or drag down the cell up until the last cell, my question is that is it possible to add this forumla into the cell and have it automatically run all the way down to the last row of data?  my forumula is

```
=VLOOKUP(B12,coloursc:carsc,2)
```

Comment: You may want to look into using VBA if you want it to be automatic. But if you don't have any blank rows in your spreadsheet you should be able to just double click the crosshairs when you hover over the bottom right corner of the cell with the formula in and it will populate all cells to the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: Simply use the column reference rather than the range reference.  If your lookup is B12 and your lookup range is C2:D154, you can simply use "=VLOOKUP(B12,C:D,2)" and you don't need to know where the end of the range is (there can be some performance issues if you have other complex calculations in the spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Excel table for your data entry. Formulas and formatting will automatically be applied to any new row in the table. You no longer need to manually copy down or pre-fill empty areas of the spreadsheet with formulas.

Learn more about tables [in this Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) and this tutorial on [Contextures.com](http://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html)